# Where can I find the mapping from Android OsConstants text to actual int value?

Tags: android

I am reading exit reasons from ApplicationExitInfo, and I'm getting an exit reason with reason nr 2 (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ApplicationExitInfo#REASON_SIGNALED) and getStatus() returns the nr 9 (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ApplicationExitInfo#getStatus()).

Where can I find the mapping from [OsConstants](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/system/OsConstants) to the actual number 9 to see what the signal is? The OsConstants pages only list out the names of the signals, not their actual values.